# how to using localStorageService in $translateProvider module config

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, angular-translate, angular-local-storage

I used angular-translate and angular-local-storage with MEANjs, all is add to module dependencies,

in app config.js:

```
  var service = {
    applicationEnvironment: window.env,
    applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
    applicationModuleVendorDependencies: ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngFileUpload', 'ui-notification',
      'LocalStorageModule', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'angularMoment', 'ngFileSaver', 'ngSanitize', 'uiCropper', 'hc.marked'],
    registerModule: registerModule
  };
```

and in init.js:

```
  angular
    .module(app.applicationModuleName)
    .config(localStorageModuleConfig)
    .config(transConfig);

  localStorageModuleConfig.$inject = ['localStorageServiceProvider'];
  function localStorageModuleConfig(localStorageServiceProvider) {
    console.log('localStorageModuleConfig');
    localStorageServiceProvider
      .setPrefix('meanTorrent')
      .setStorageType('localStorage')
      .setDefaultToCookie(true)
      .setNotify(true, true);
  }

  transConfig.$inject = ['$translateProvider', 'localStorageService'];
  function transConfig($translateProvider, localStorageService) {
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);

    var user_lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    user_lang = user_lang.substr(0, 2) || 'en';

    var storage_lang = localStorageService.get('storage_user_lang');
    user_lang = storage_lang || user_lang;

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage(user_lang);
  }
```

I already include all .js files in html, when runing, I got error `Unknown provider: localStorageService`，I know in config part, must used provider, but if i used `localStorageServiceProvider` in `transConfig`, it can not to  `.get('storage_user_lang')`

any way to used service in config? or how to use provider to call self service`s method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject service to configuration block (only providers and constants),

I used window.localStorage to solve this issue [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).